# Parallel computing in R. Is there way to flush.console()?

Tags: r, user-interface, parallel-processing

I am using R package snowfall. Is there way to use flush.console() on my master instance while running the parallel computing? My R master console freezes when I do parallel computing and I want to avoid this..

My minimum example is the following.
I have a function myFun.

```
myFun  <- function(x)
   {
    for (i in 1 : 10)
     { 
       Sys.sleep(1)
       flush.console()
     }
   }
```

This function does the job (i.e., console get flushed) when it is run by itself:

```
 myFun(1)
```

But when I run this in parallel, R console freezes.

```
 library("snowfall")
 sfInit(parallel=TRUE,cpus=3,type="SOCK")
 x <- 1 : 100
 res.list <- sfClusterApplyLB(x,myFun)
```

I would love to flush the console while parallel coding.

Thank you

Comment: Are you running a script?  Put it into the script.

Comment: @RichardScriven I added scripts.

Comment: I think it is a problem of the GUI begin used rather than a problem of R. If you don't want to freeze your console, you can either use the terminal R or R Studio. R Studio is more responsive in many cases.

Comment: Are you trying to flush output from the workers to the console of the master?

Comment: @SteveWeston Weston I am using Mac. My master console freezes and my Mac (10.7.5) shows loading wheel when the sfClusterApplyLB is called. All I want to do is avoid this to happen..

Comment: @RichardScriven I am writing a R package and it would be great if the problem does not happen to any users of my R package.

Answer (score 2):

Since the "flush.console" function updates the R console, it doesn't make sense in a cluster worker. Although the master R session may be interactive, the workers are not.

You could use the "interactive" function to avoid possible problems in a non-interactive context:

```
myFun <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:10) { 
    Sys.sleep(1)
    if (interactive()) flush.console()
  }
}
```

Now "flush.console" will be executed when the master calls "myFun", but not when the workers call it. This technique is often used with other inherently interactive functions such as "browser".